# Write number of files on basis of size of data in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a use case on which I'm working.

I have 100GB of data and I read it through Spark. After reading and applying some transformations, I write that data back to storage.

> Problem is while writing data I partition it by Country. Now, what
> happens is, that for some countries, data is in GBs, but for some
> countries data is in MBs.
>
> As I'm using Coalesce (100) so there is no problem in saving GBs of
> data in 100 files but saving few MBs in 100 file is problem.
>
> So somehow I want to create number of files in a partition on the
> basis of number of rows of that specific Country.

Comment: Can you add an example as after reformatting I cannot quite follow the question.

Comment: I get almost 100 TB of data daily. Data has a column of country. So I partition the data by Country and save it to AWS S3 with coalesce value of 100. Now let's deep dive in to the data, now some countries have only 100 number of rows, let's take Somalia for the sake of example. So when I coalesce it with 100, I got 100 number of files for total 100 rows i.e. one row in each file and this is very disturbing. Now I want to dynamically create number of files depending on the data. out of 100TB data, UK has number of rows equivalent to 10 TB, continued in next comment

Comment: so 10TB divided into 100 number of files is reasonable but 100 rows equivalent to 10 MB divided into 100 number of files is not reasonable, so I want to control number of files created i.e. coalesce(100) with respect to the size of resulting partition.